# How to get my video autoplay and at a certain time after clicking on an anchoring link width target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, iframe

I have a simple link with an anchor that lead to the same page but with a target="_blank".

Like that :

```
<a href="www.test.be/#part2" target="_blank" onclick="playme()">Click here</a>
```

And this part2 is a div containing a video that I want to be autoplay at 60 sec of the beginning. 
So I try this in JS :

```
function playme() {
document.getElementById("video1").src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/code?start=60&autoplay=1&controls=0&amp;rel=0';}
```

The anchor works but the video doesn't play because of the target="_blank" I think.

So is it possible in JS or in PHP to get the video autoplay after clicking on a anchoring link with a target="_blank" ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are invoking JS in one tab but opening your page in another, where that link isn't clicked

Comment: Rather than using `_blank` why don't you just make it pop out in a modal instead with ajax? Some do block pop up windows; I do.

Comment: Hi Luca, yes indeed I understand that it doesn't work and that's why I thought to PHP but I don't really know how to do it, probably with a if but then I'm lost

Comment: Hello Fred, it seems like I need to open up the same page in a new tab but I'm will check for a modal and what I can do with that

Comment: @FlorianeA if you want to get someone's particular attention, you need to do as I did here for you using the @ symbol followed by their name, then a space, then your message ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii- Thank you for the advice Fred :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you combine `window.onload` function and `window.location.hash`? If window is fully loaded and hash is `part2`, play the video!

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.location.hash.substring(1) == "part2") {
        playme();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0tkvLg8v/) is sample code with above code, and since JSFiddle cannot display `_blank` simulation well, make a HTML file in your PC and try the code.

Comment: Hello Alfred, 

Thank you for your answer
I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work since I have to use the target blank

Comment: @FlorianeA Just edited my post adding sample code with JSFiddle link. Check it out

Comment: Thank you @Alfred Woo for the Fiddle your solution is working fine !